# calling a stored procedure to be used in a where statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, where-clause

So I have a query with the following WHERE statement

```
WHERE
    (SELECT max(pa.txndate) 
                    FROM player_activity pa 
                    WHERE pa.userID = customer_profile.userID
        ) =  date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

My query actually has several other sub-queries, but I was told that all my sub-queries kill the performance, therefore I need to use stored procedures.

Created the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getMaxPaDate`()
BEGIN
    SELECT userid, max(txndate) 
    FROM player_activity  
    GROUP by userid;
END
```

However, I don't have a clue on how to call stored procedures, so unsurprisingly, the following didn't work for me.

```
WHERE
     call getMaxPaDate() = date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Help?

Comment: You need to make it a function, not a procedure, and it will have to take `userID` as a parameter. But I don't think that will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Making it a stored procedure won't improve performance. What you need to do is use a join.

```
SELECT cp.*
FROM customer_profile AS cp
JOIN (SELECT userID
      FROM player_activity
      GROUP BY userID
      HAVING MAX(pa.txndate) = TODAY() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS pa
ON cp.userID = pa.userID
```

Comment: I actually just figured out how to run the query using a smaller table. However, if I absolutely had to use a stored procedure (as shown above), how would I reference it in my where statement?

Comment: You don't use a stored procedure, you use a function. Then use `WHERE func(pa.userID) = cp.userID`